# CCK field not showing in JSON view

Tags: entities

I have created a new CCK field and am trying to show it in a JSON view. It shows in the preview however when I go to the path I created for it the field won't show. I've turned off caching on views and done everything else I can think of but it won't work. When I run the SQL on the DB it does show the column and the entered data, and it shows in places that I"m using it on my site.

One really weird thing is that it shows here:

http://metrotrains.com.au/lines/network_stations.json

but not here:

http://www.metrotrains.com.au/lines/network_stations.json

The field I'm talking about is called "facilitiesparking" under the first node.

Any help would be great. :)